# Which method is better to use

Tags: android

In my application I need to send `SMS` on a regular interval of 5 minutes. I can use a thread that will run in background using the `wait()` method, then I can wait for 5 minutes and send `SMS`  at an interval of 5 minute.

I can also use a repeating alarm with 5 minute interval and then send the `SMS`. 
Which one is better to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the AlarmManager for this, as this will probably use less resources, also, this is a system facility that was already prepared for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well as per My Suggession, Alarm is better then the Thread Class. However Have you try TimerTask Class ?

Just look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm) example of TimerTask Class.